# Minimal polynomial of a complex matrix

Tags: geometry, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, minimal-polynomials

Let $\varphi(t)=\frac 16[(3t-1)(2t-1)(t-k)]$ the minimal polynomial of a Matrix $A_k\in M(n,\mathbb{C})$. Find all values of $k$ for which $A_k$ is invertible. Then, show that $A_1^{-1}=6A_1^2-11A_1+6Id$. For the first part I wrote that the characteristic polynomial of $A_k$ must be $\chi_{A_k}(t)=(t-1/3)^x(t-1/2)^y(t-k)^z$ such that $x+y+z=n$. So, $det(A_k)=(1/3)^x(1/2)^yk^z$ which is not zero $iff$ $k$ is not zero. For the second part, $\varphi_{A_1}(A_1)=0$ $\implies$ $6A_1^3-11A_1^2+6A_1-I_n=0$, multiplying for $A_1^{-1}$ I get the result. I'd like to know if I get the right solution. Thank you.

Comment: I do not see your solution: neither right nor wrong.

Comment: Without proof, just look at $k_A(\lambda)=\det(A-\lambda I)$. What happens is: $k_A(0)=\det A$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** $A_k$ fails to be invertible if and only if it has $0$ as an eigenvalue

Comment: @psidaga It is not true that every matrix with $0$ as an eigenvalue has a zero column. So no, not right

Comment: Sorry, I mean the representative matrix of your linear function which has the eigenvalues on the diagonal. In that case the zero columns belong to the kernel